# Import error after manual installation from git

Tags: python

I manually installed vnfmanager package from the follwing git url

https://github.com/TCS-TelcoCloud/vnfmanager

and followed the installation steps as specified

```
git clone https://github.com/TCS-TelcoCloud/vnfmanager.git
python setup.py install
```

Installation is done without any errors in ("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ ") But, when i try to import the module from python interpreter am getting "ImportError: No module named vnf_manager "

Am working with python 2.7 and here are some more details on it

```
which -a python
/usr/bin/python
```

sys.path output from python

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vnfsvc-2015.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_vnfsvcclient-2015.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vnfmanager-2015.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

when i try to import

```
import vnfmanager.vnf_manager
```

am getting error

```
ImportError: No module named vnf_manager
```

Please Help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a virtualenv, the import works here.

But there are other problems with that package. It has a lot of undeclared dependencies, and it mentions some `vnfsvc_examples` directory that does not exist. I'd contact the package author.

If you install all the dependencies, it seems to work:

```
virtualenv test
source test/bin/activate
pip install pastescript oslo.db oslo.messaging oslo.config eventlet pyyaml
python setup.py install
python -c "import vnfmanager.vnf_manager"
```

Note: you may need to install some additional compile-time dependencies first, like a compiler and the Python development headers. This is OS-specific. On a Debian-based Linux, try `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev`.

Do not manually install Python packages into your system-wide Python installation. It can break things in nasty ways. Your system-wide Python installation should be managed by your OS package manager. I.e. do not run pip or `setup.py install` as root. Instead, use virtualenv.

Comment: No, am trying to access the main function in vnf_manager.py which resides under vnfmanager folder. 

If you look into the repo - (https://github.com/TCS-TelcoCloud/vnfmanager) we have vnfmanager folder, under than vnf_manager file exists.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that file. ``import vnfmanager.vnf_manager`` works here (in a virtualenv), it just errors because of all the missing dependencies like yaml, eventlet, oslo and so on. The package author should fix that. That package has a ton of dependencies, and none of them is properly declared.

If you use virtualenv and install all the dependencies yourself, maybe the package will work.

Comment: thanks . i have never done installation with virutal environment. would it be possible to share the commands or steps you followed ?